# Physics behind impedance matching and reflection

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electricity, electric-fields, electronics

I have been looking for cause of signal reflections in transmission lines everywhere it is concluded that the reason is impedance mismatch. I understand that if the impedance changes in the path of the signal travels, then reflection will occur but what I could not understand is the physics behind it. How does including a series resistor of the characteristic impedance suppress the reflections? Since the direction of reflected voltage is opposite, does it mean the point at which the impedance changes becomes high in potential or anything else ? 
I understand what is happening but not how it's happening, can anyone give directions to understand the physics behind this?

Comment: See section 22-6, "A ladder network", in the chapter [AC Circuits](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_22.html) of the second volume of the Feynman Lectures.

Comment: thank you @NickD